# Dynamically Changing the CSS in Tailwind

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working with **Next.js** and **Tailwind CSS**. I am trying to change the theme dynamically. Below is the content from a state inside a context.

I have 8 colors, each with 5 shades *(I have provided only one shade here to keep the message short)*. Whichever color I set in the initial state, it works fine.
When I use the setter function to set another color, the **bg**, **text** i.e. `themeColor.bg.dark` etc work fine but the **hover**, **peerChecked** and **after** i.e. `themeColor.bg.hover.dark` etc. don't work.

Moreover, once I have set all the colors in the initial state one by one, everything starts working, even the setter (like probably all the colors are now stored in cache,) until I refresh the page, and the issue is still the same.

**Initial State**

```js
bg: {
  "dark": "bg-themeColor1Dark",
  "hover": {
    "dark": "hover:bg-themeColor1Dark",
  },
  "peerChecked": {
    "dark": "peer-checked:bg-themeColor1Dark",
  },
  "after": {
    "dark": "after:bg-themeColor1Dark",
  }
},
```

**Setting the new state**

```js
bg: {
  "dark": `bg-${themeColor}Dark`,
  "hover": {
    "dark": `hover:bg-${themeColor}Dark`,
  },
  "peerChecked": {
    "dark": `peer-checked:bg-${themeColor}Dark`,
  },
  "after": {
    "dark": `after:bg-${themeColor}Dark`,
  }
},
```